# Unable to pull contacts with NO accounts tied using CRM SDK FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

Using the below fetchxml, it is pulling contacts only that has account tied up. I want to pull contacts that has an account tied up [if so account name] and also contacts with no account tied up together. I have outer join but still it doesn't work. The below fetchxml is pulling only contacts that has account number tied up but not all active contacts with no account information.

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="contact" >   
    <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    <attribute name="lastname" />    
    <attribute name="firstname" />    
    <attribute name="accountidname" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="accountid" link-type="outer" >
      <attribute name="name" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: the fetchxml looks correct, do your tests using FetchXML Builder (it's an XrmToolBox tool) and see if there you are seeing the correct data retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one issue, the attribute `parentcustomerid` in contact entity should be used instead of `accountid`.

So the join condition should be:

`<link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" link-type="outer" >`

Complete query:

```
<fetch top="50" >
  <entity name="contact" >   
    <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    <attribute name="lastname" />    
    <attribute name="firstname" />    
    <attribute name="accountidname" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" link-type="outer" >
      <attribute name="name" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Looks like this `accountid` in contact is just guid not a lookup and moreover a virtual field. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/270092/how-accountid-is-filled-from-webapi-soap-endpoint-perspective-on-contact-entity)